# will there be any negative impact in using the option usePowerOf2Sizes

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb for our Application .
I ran the `db.setProfilingLevel(1,25)` on the mongo shell to identify the slow queries from `system.profile` collection .

I observed that the read operations are fast , but the update operations are very slow

This is a sample of my mongostat

```
insert/s query/s update/s delete/s getmore/s command/s flushes/s mapped  vsize    res faults/s locked % idx miss %    q t|r|w  conn       time
       0     950      469        0         0       471         0  10396  12295   3207       27     34.9          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:49
       0     838      418        0         0       422         0  10396  12295   3209       21     34.6          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:50
       0    1005      502        0         0       504         0  10396  12295   3211       21     35.5          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:51
       0     837      410        0         0       418         0  10396  12295   3212       20     35.7          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:52
       0     754      377        0         0       379         0  10396  12295   3214       19     36.7          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:53
       0     841      420        0         0       422         0  10396  12295   3216       24     35.9          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:54
       0     877      438        0         0       442         0  10396  12295   3217       23     37.2          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:55
       0     799      393        0         0       395         0  10396  12295   3219       21       37          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:56
       0     947      471        0         0       479         0  10396  12295   3221       26       39          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:57
       0     855      427        0         0       429         0  10396  12295   3222       24     38.4          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:58
       0    1007      504        0         0       506         0  10396  12295   3224       31       36          0      0|0|0   152   07:18:59
       0     841      413        0         0       417         0  10396  12295   3226       23     37.2          0      0|0|0   152   07:19:00
```

The stats are from dev environment , cant assume really from prod environment .

As per the architecture i cannot reduce the index size on that collection , but i saw that usePowerOf2Sizes can help me in this case in improving the write/update response time in mongodb .

I have heard lot of usePowerOf2Sizes , which says that

As usePowerOf2Sizes can reduce fragmentation .
all data will be set in mmemory and performance will be great .
With this option MongoDB will be able to more effectively reuse space.
usePowerOf2Sizes is useful for collections where you will be inserting and deleting large numbers of documents to ensure that MongoDB will effectively use space on disk.

I want to know if there will be any negative impact in using the option usePowerOf2Sizes ?? I have got 17 collections in my mongodb and want to use usePowerOf2Sizes for only one collection .

Please let me know , thanks in advance .

Comment: Powerof2sizes allocates more space per document irresptive of whether that document needs it or not, as such it can increase working set, resources required to gather from disk (can increase page fault count) and IO

Comment: thanks a lot , i googled but didn't find any negative impact .